# What jquery event listener should i use for a user swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I want users to be able to swipe on section 2 that causes a function to manipulate section 1.

What event listener is the most effective for me to use to listen for a user swipe (left or right) on section two?

Comment: Thanks, but looking for the most effective. ie. works across all devices and is easily written. I've looked at lots of different examples.

Comment: That question is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are available in jquery

```
touchstart
touchmove 
touchend
touchenter
touchleave
touchcancel
```

And you need to calculate if it is touch left/right on your own.  Here is an [example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml)

But you might want to consider jquery mobile that has `swipeleft swiperight` events